# How to set background color for full height of a DIV?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My Ruby on Rails application uses BootStrap for easier layout rendering. I define rows and columns:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 left_border">
      <ul class="" role="menu">
        <li><%= link_to t('Groups'), groups_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('Users'), users_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('Parameters'), "#" %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">

      <%= yield %>

      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The left-border class only sets the background color for the element:

```
.left_border {
   background-color: $grayDarker;
}
```

It works fine, but the first column's background is set for its content only, not for the whole cell. If the <%= yield %> function returns lots of lines, I get a small grey box on the left including the menu, where I'd like to display a full grey column.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: try giving <div class="row  left_border">
    <div class="col-md-3"> or .left_border {
   background-color: #ccc;
}

Comment: Are you sure the column itself is as tall as you want? If not, try to add a test temporaty border to colums. Or, just use the browser developer tools to see the columns areas. It could simply be the table height to be 100% or the like, depending on the dom context.

Comment: You are right Stratboy, the height of the row is not applied to the column. Stating height:100% has no effect. Could it be relarted to the late inclusion of the <%= yield %> content ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally switched to the css3 Flexible Box feature, which provides a smart way of designing grids:

1 - I created the classes I needed in my css file

```
/* flex containers */
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  }

.flex-container-v {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  }

.flex-item {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 80%
  }

.flex-item-border {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 20%;
  }
```

2 - I organise my display blocks using these classes

```
   <div class="flex-container-v">
     <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item-border logo">
                <br/>
                <%= image_tag("k.png", alt: "KeyMan") %>
                <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
                <nav class="top_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <li> <%= t('User') %>: <%= link_to (current_user.first_name + ' ' + current_user.name), edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                        <li> | <%= link_to t('Sign_out'), destroy_user_session_path, method: "delete" %></li>
                        <% else %>
                        <li> <%= link_to t('Sign_in'), new_user_session_path %></li>
                        <% end %>
                        <li> | <%= link_to t('Help'), "#" %> </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1><%= t('Cryptographic Keys Manager') %></h1>             </div>
        </div>
...
```

And it works fine !